# Using Streams to Get Even Numbers From Array of Ints

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

I'm trying to take an array of ints, get all of the even numbers from it, and put those even numbers into an ArrayList, then return the ArrayList. I have the code worked out with a for loop below, but want to basically condense this for loop into one statement using java streams. I tried doing so below it in the commented out return statement at the bottom, but can't figure it out.

```
  public static ArrayList<Integer> evens(int[] results) {
    ArrayList<Integer> evens = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      if (results[i] % 2 == 0) {
        Integer num = Integer.valueOf(results[i]);
        evens.add(num);
      }
    }
    return evens;
    // return Arrays.stream(results).filter(i -> i % 2 ==
    // 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

Comment: Why must you return an `ArrayList<Integer>`. It's better to return the abstract type, ie `List<Integer>`. If you do, the "one line" will be a lot smaller. What are you having problems with? Try starting with `Arrays.stream(results).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)` and see how you go.

Answer (score 3):

You were close.

`Arrays.stream` on an `int` array returns an `IntStream`. You have to convert it to a `Stream<Integer>` (via `boxed()`) before collecting it to a `List<Integer>`.

And the return type of the method should be `List<Integer>`.

```
public static List<Integer> evens(int[] results) {
    return Arrays.stream(results)
                 .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
                 .boxed ()
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Eran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68062701/4405757) explains what you need to do to convert an `IntStream` to a `Stream<Integer>`. It is also recommended to return the abstract type (`List`) rather than a concrete type like an `ArrayList`. If you need to return an `ArrayList` for some reason, you can use a `Collectors.toCollection` and pass a supplier for the collection to be returned.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> evens(int[] results) {
    return Arrays.stream(results)
             .boxed()
             .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
             .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
}
```